# "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found" when installing memcached on Windows Server

Tags: php, memcached

I am using XAMPP 1.7.0. I have [followed these instructions](http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-install-memcached-on-xampp-on-windows-7) to install memcached and it works fine for Windows 7 but when I have it installed in Windows Server it shows

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found

I have tried many times to do this but am failing.

Comment: The extension might be inactive! check your php.ini configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been solved here: [Class 'Memcache' not found & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883378/class-memcache-not-found-php)

Your problem is probably that the dll file you used is not working with your PHP version;

This is your solution (I quote from my own answer)

> I found the working dll files for PHP 5.4.4
>
> I don't knowhow stable they are but they work for sure. Credits goes
>   to this link.
>
> http://x32.elijst.nl/php_memcache-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip
>
> http://x32.elijst.nl/php_memcache-5.4-vc9-x86.zip
>
> It is the 2.2.5.0 version, I noticed after compiling it (for PHP
>   5.4.4).
>
> Please note that it is not 2.2.6 but works. I also mirrored them in my
>   own FTP. Mirror links:
>
> http://mustafabugra.com/resim/php_memcache-5.4-vc9-x86.zip
>   http://mustafabugra.com/resim/php_memcache-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip

Comment: Wow, I've been having this problem for a while and these links for PHP 5.4 just did the trick. Thanks!