# Missing packages on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached

I've upgraded PHP to version 5.4 using this guide:
http://www.barryodonovan.com/index.php/2012/05/22/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-and-php-5-4-again

Now when i hit "$php -v" it throws following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/memcached.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/memcached.so: undefined symbol: memcached_touch in Unknown on line 0
```

How can i properly install "memcached" library? Package manager reports that i've already got latest version. I even tried to reinstall it to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need all extensions in the correct version. We had this problem here before some time. At the moment only the memcache beta supports php5.4 on this site you get a compiled module.

[Class 'Memcache' not found & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883378/class-memcache-not-found-php)